# Getting number from database, then subtracting it doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried creating a script to prevent spamming. Every 30 seconds will allow you to post again. I am using `time()` to use it (php unix time) and then uploading it to the user's profile. So `lastpost`=time(); (basically)

```
$ayy = $user['lastpost'];
die($ayy);
```

That returns the user last posted. For this example, the last time the user has posted was 14423658.
When I apply simple math to it, such as

```
die($ayy - 3);
```

it will output nothing.
If I convert the value to a integer, doing

```
$ayy = intval($user['lastpost']);
```

The `$ayy` value will just become null (blank). How I know this is when I perform

```
die($ayy);
```

It outputs nothing.
If I do

```
$ayy = intval($user['lastpost']);
die($ayy - 1);
```

or

```
$ayy = $user['lastpost'];
die(intval($ayy - 1));
```

They all output nothing.
You'd expect something like this to be very simple, but I have spent days pondering this, and it is really frustrating.

If you do contribute, thanks.

**EDIT**
When var_dump is applied to $ayy, this is what it outputs:
`string(14423658)`
when `intval` is applied to `$ayy`, this is also what it outputs: `int(14423658)`. It was working the whole time (with `intval`) but it didn't output anything. **Problem Solved**, but why is it outputting blank?

Comment: debug with `var_dump($user['lastpost'])` not sure why your using die so much here

Comment: @nogad read edit.

Comment: http://ideone.com/8Edtes cant reproduce your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php (exit is equivalent for die):

> if status is integer it's not printed.

If you want to print it with die(I don't know why) do like this `die((string)$ayy).`